# Debug java client traffic through inhouse proxy server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy

Some java code can ask a webservice through an inhouse proxy server and some other code does not even use the proxy. Both use the same configuration files and startuo arguments

Because of this I think I can't use a local proxy (or I am not aware of a pass through proxy in eclipse or on windows XP)

I tried some start arguments to see the handshake as

```
-Djavax.net.debug=all
```

which works for ssl after proxy but not for the proxy server handshake.
Also the sysinternals suite tcpmon or eclipse's tcp monitpr, didn't show much

Is there and VM argument or sniffer which does show what happens between eclipse/java client and a proxy server ?

Comment: I use [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for these types of network tracings.  It has a sharp learning curve but it is very useful once you understand how to use it.

Comment: thanks, didn't dive deep and just tried wirshark. It shows that aproxy dialog is used, but not which user is used for the authentication...Probably best to have some Java log to see the handshake results...